# How to boot a cd before windows loads?

Tags: windows, boot, compact-disc

I changed my bios settings to 1st boot CD-Rom, 2nd boot CD-Rom, 3rd boot CD-Rom.

So in theory it should not load windows up but for some reason it does. I am not sure why this is happening.

It is like ignoring my boot options.

I am not sure what more information to give you.

thanks

Comment: That's odd, no BIOS i've ever used lets me choose the same device for 3 places. Usually just a list that you can move items up or down with. Are you saving changes on exit?

Comment: If you've set the 1st boot option to CD it should use that - assuming you've put a bootable CD/DVD in the drive of course.

Comment: are you sure the CD/DVD is bootable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting the boot sequence in the BIOS to boot from CDROM first isn't the most reliable method.

modern computers have a Boot Options Menu (usually F12 or F10 or ESC during the POST screen), use this instead.

Edit: when you set the first 3 boot devices to CDROM, did you leave "Boot From Other Device" enabled? that would explain why the system is still booting after failing to boot from the first three.

Answer (score 1):

Def sounds like a non-bootable CD/DVD... What CD is it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is impossible : The BIOS only lets you reposition boot media.

You're likely not on the right BIOS menu.
Take a picture of the BIOS screen with a digital camera and post it for us to comment upon.

**EDIT**

I see this is a Phoenix Award BIOS.
I guess that this is not a new machine (please correct me if I'm wrong).
Windows is probably being booted since "Boot From Other Device" is checked and the CD is not bootable, so the BIOS searches for some other boot device. This option is normally meant for USB boot, but it may also work in your case for the hard disk.
I wonder if the boot CD is a DVD but the drive only supports a CD.
If this is not the case, then the CD you're trying to boot is not a boot CD or is dead.

Comment: Someone else just did that in a different post. Sounds possible. Probably a 3rd world manufacturer's bios though.

Comment: ahh, some BIOS actoally allow to use the same device (i.e. CDROM) as 1st, 2nd and 3rd boot device at the same time.

Comment: I would still like to see a picture of this marvel.

Comment: Voilá: http://upload.removed.us/files/4/Leigh%20Ann%20049.JPG

Comment: GISed this: bios boot order 3x cdrom ... the 4th pic :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the claims, BIOS'es differ from each other.  There some that will "help" you by finding a bootable device and using it.  Some will even put it back into the list!

They usually do this if they can't boot what you specified.  So the "CD not bootable" ideas are valid.  Also "drive having trouble reading the CD"--personal experience with that one.